# No ADB connection to Transformer Prime TF201 on 4.1.1

Tags: adb, asus-eee-pad-transformer

ADB connection to Transformer Prime TF201 on 4.1.1

With USB Debugging disabled I can see the TF as expected.

With USB Debugging enabled I can see an entry under Device Manager for ASUS Transformer Prime ADB Interface with no warnings or errors. However when I attempt to use ADB to connect I'm not getting any devices returned.

Screenshot here:

[image: Screenshot of ADB command window]

If I plug my phone in and list devices I get a single entry returned which works as expected, SHELL etc works normally.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue with the computer I was running ADB on. I took the transformer to work and ADB worked perfectly first time.

Comment: I have the same problem. What do you mean with"I was running ADB on"?

Comment: The computer I was using to connect with ADB. I used a different computer and ADB was working fine, it was obviously a configuration with my PC at home, a different PC worked first time.